# How to change image(src) of ImageView with button mouse-click on Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a simple click to change the images(src) of ImageView with button click. But the images should load randomly from directory. I created variables and used Random function to achieve this but got stuck creating and linking the function with even.

[image]

And Here is the complete Java code:

```
public class CardsGame extends Application {

    // Variables
    String img1, img2, img3;
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

    public CardsGame() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 68; i++) {
            array.add("imagescards/" + i + ".png");
        }

        img1 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
        img2 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
        img3 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create FlowGrid
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        // Create Image View
        ImageView cardImg1 = new ImageView(("imagescards/1.png"));
        cardImg1.setFitHeight(200);
        cardImg1.setFitWidth(150);

        ImageView cardImg2 = new ImageView(("imagescards/2.png"));
        cardImg2.setFitHeight(200);
        cardImg2.setFitWidth(150);

        ImageView cardImg3 = new ImageView(("imagescards/1.png"));
        cardImg3.setFitHeight(200);
        cardImg3.setFitWidth(150);

        // Create Button
        Button play = new Button("Play");
        play.setMinWidth(100.0);
        play.setOnAction(new EnlargeHandler());

        // Add nodes to pane
        pane.getChildren().addAll(cardImg1, cardImg2, cardImg3, play);

        // Create Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 460, 250);

        // Add scene to stage
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Cards Game");

        // Show Stage
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public void refresh() {
        img1 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
        img2 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
        img3 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);

    }

    class EnlargeHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            refresh();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed Following:

```
public void refresh() {
 img1 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
 img2 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
 img3 = (String) array.get((int) (Math.random() * 67) + 1);
}
```

Adding the following code at the end helped.

```
play.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
      cardImg1.setImage(new Image("imagescards/" + CardsGame() + ".png"));
      cardImg2.setImage(new Image("imagescards/" + CardsGame() + ".png"));
      cardImg3.setImage(new Image("imagescards/" + CardsGame() + ".png"));
 }
```